# How to split a list in c++?

Tags: c++

Im trying to implement merge sort with an unsorted linked list but need to use the stl list in C++. I understand how to implement it with a linked list that I would make myself but am confused on how to use the stl list.

For example, how would I got about splitting up the list? Since there are no next pointers to set to null, I don't get how I go about recursively splitting the list. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The stdlib doesn't give you raw access to the underlying structure of `std::list`. Why not just use `std::list<T>::sort()`?

Comment: @CruzJean There is [`std::list::splice`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ split std list into two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690083/c-split-std-list-into-two-lists)

Answer (score 4):

The conventional approach (for C++) would be to leave the list itself intact.

Instead of splitting the list, have your code work with iterators, and to "split the list", pass a pair of iterators to only part of the list instead of the whole thing.